# Production SSL with NGINX + ANGULAR + Docker

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, deployment, production

as always thank you for your tips and advice.

I have an angular application which i want to deploy with Nginx. I am using certbot to create the certificates and that works fine. Meaning i am able to access my domain. But the domain gives me an error, since it does not find all the production files. Here is my angular dockerfile:

```
#stage 1
FROM node:10.16.0 as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app/
RUN npm install
ARG configuration=production
RUN npm run build -- --prod --configuration=$configuration

#stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/angular-SPA /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx-config.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

This is my nginx-config.conf:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

and I have a folder with a docker-compose.yml and a nginx.conf. I am not sure if this is a good practice or not. But this is how the developer before me did it.

In the nginx folder, this is the docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  image: nginx
  volumes:
   - ./:/usr/share/nginx/html
   - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf 
   - /etc/letsencrypt:/root/letsencrypt
  ports:
   - "80:80"
   - "443:443"
  command: /bin/bash -c "nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

and this is the nginx config for nginx.

```
server {
    listen              80;
    server_name example.com;
    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        allow all;
        #default_type "text/plain";
    }
    location / {
        return 301 https://example.com;
    }
}
server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         example.com;
    ssl_certificate     /root/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /root/letsencrypt/live/example-0001/privkey.pem;
    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        allow all;
        default_type "text/plain";
    }
    location = / {
        proxy_pass        http://PRIVATE_IP_OF_AWS_INSTANCE:9090/index.html;
    }
}
```

PRIVATE_IP_OF_AWS_INSTANCE is the private ip of my AWS EC2 instance.
I have my angular container running on port 9090:80.

This are the error I get when i try to access example.com:

example.com/:15 GET https://example.com/runtime-es2015.858f8dd898b75fe86926.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
example.com/:12 GET https://example.com/styles.45c31720860b353d5204.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
example.com/:15 GET https://example.com/polyfills-es2015.5728f680576ca47e99fe.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
favicon.ico:1 GET https://example.com/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)

Please help, any advice or tips are welcome.

Comment: Hello @freecks, have you found some info about that?